# Django change external user-facing field name

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a model that will have two similar "id"-like fields. One will be the primary key, one will be the a human-readable id.

On the backed/in the model, I have differentiated them as such

```
pk_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # internal only, incrementing int
ext_id = models.CharField(max_length=128) # external facing, words+int
```

When the user does a query to get a list of the models, I want to EXCLUDE `pk_id` entirely, and have `ext_id` appear simply under the name `id`.  Like this:

```
{
'id' : 'name_title_001' # same as ext_id
'other_fields' : 'bla bla bla'
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you talking about the output from a rest framework serializer, a `values()` queryset or adding a property to the model?

Comment: I'm using DRF, sorry I forgot to mention - so yes, this would be output exposed via serializes when you do a GET to retrieve a queryset of these objects

Answer (score 1):

suppose your model name is SomeModel; Update your serializers as

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.CharField(source='ext_id', read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = (
            'id',
            # other fields excluding pk_id and ext_id
        )
```